# export 'default' (imported as 'Cookies') was not found in 'react-cookie' (possible exports unknown)

Tags: reactjs, react-cookie

I am getting above error while trying to access cookie from browser using 'react-cookie'.

Here is the code i am trying:

```
    import Cookies from 'react-cookie';
    
    function App() {
    
      const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
      const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const tokenFromCookie = Cookies.get("accessToken");
        setToken(tokenFromCookie);
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this object Cookies is imported to use with CLASS Component

```
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
```

and for Function Component use useCookies like this

```
/// here the error
    import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie';
    
    function App() {
    
      const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
      const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['accessToken']);
      
      // this part aren't usefull because u have access to the cookies using useCookies
      // const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
    
      // useEffect(() => {
      //   const tokenFromCookie = cookies.accessToken;
      //   setToken(tokenFromCookie);
      // }, []);
```

Comment: this solution is not working.

Comment: const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['name']);

Comment: @VijayRathod20 here is the full anser for ur issue the {} arent required for this library but it recommended

Comment: @VijayRathod20 in index.jsx dont forget  import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
<CookiesProvider><App /></CookiesProvider>